# Android in-app billing API v3: getting started

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-billing

This has been asked many times, but in all the questions there wasn't any guide complete enough.

- All the guides recycle the Sample project bundled with the billing
  library, even if on Android Developers it's clearly said that the
  `util` package should be written from scratch/heavily edited instead of just copying
  the stock one.
- There are no directions on which data send to and how to verify on a personal server if the purchase is legitimate.
- There's no hint, basically, on how to make the sample code stronger,i.e. on how to secure the key in a serverless environment, on how to generate and check a purchase payload and so on.

Maybe I've missed some line or I'm just a bit scared and confused, but I'm asking for some complete resource to consult and some clarification on the three doubts I wrote above.

Answer (score 4):

Since nobody is answering, I'll make an answer with useful resources for people unable to implement IAB.

### New Sample references

[This](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) library is very lightweight and essential, it just works with managed products, but a [fork](https://github.com/lopper/android-inapp-billing-v3) also adds support for subscription products. Both the libraries don't offer any kind of support for querying the inventory, they just handle the purchase process, which is a better approach for my *forma mentis*. This library paired with the guides on Android Developers makes everything clearer.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-h2ESH71hAI) shows the very basic implementation, this also just implements the purchase request and not the verification/inventory query.

### Remote Server Verification

[This article](http://evendanan.net/2012/03/In-App-Purchase-Verification-using-PHP-OR-Making-sure-you-ain-t-getting-ripped-off-PHP-style/) shows a simple method to verify purchase data with your public key, so you're not forced to insert it inside your own application.
[This guide](http://blog.goforyt.com/validating-android-app-purchases-laravel/) shows the necessary steps to achieve validation with a PHP backend using Laravel.